# Как отлавить событие, добавления контактов, в группу?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть группа, работает обязательная подписка на канал, как прописать код, если пользователь, не добавил, участников в группу, чтобы не смог написать в группу, чтобы код проверял, добавил ли, контакты в группу или нет.

Самое главное, чтобы это действовало, только на одну публикацию и минимальное количество, от 20 контактов.

Приведу пример, пользователь группы, подписался на канал, снял ограничения и публикует и бот телеграм, проверяет, было ли, добавление контактов, перед публикацией, если не было, устанавливает ограничения навсегда. Соответственно, если потом, пользователь добавил контакты, бот снимает ограничения.